# Variable 'i' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final

Tags: java, android, inner-classes, final

I'm trying to send value to another activity `intent.putExtra("doctor",String.valueOf(items.get(i)));`
 but it gives error. That's "**Variable 'i' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final**". The code is running in the for loop so I can't give final value because it's **iterator**.

How can we solve it?

**Part of code**

```
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
items.add(options[i]);                            
spinnerDialog=new SpinnerDialog(NewActivity.this,items,"Search","Close");// With No Animation
spinnerDialog=new SpinnerDialog(NewActivity.this,items,"Search",R.style.DialogAnimations_SmileWindow,"Close");// With   Animation

spinnerDialog.setCancellable(true); // for cancellable
spinnerDialog.setShowKeyboard(false);// for open keyboard by default
spinnerDialog.bindOnSpinerListener(new OnSpinerItemClick() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(String item, int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(NewActivity.this,PrescriptionActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("doctor",String.valueOf(items.get(i)));
        NewActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

    }
});
findViewById(R.id.show).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        spinnerDialog.showSpinerDialog();
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Use `position` instead of `i`

Comment: How I didn't see it! Thanks, it works.

Comment: `final int j = i;` and then `get(j)` would have worked too. But using `position` is better.

Answer (score 0):

The variables used in the anonymous classes implementations (or lambda expressions) must be effectively final, or else the undefined behavior would happen.

I suppose that you want to handle on click action the `item` at the position obtained from the method using the `int position`, not from the outer loop. Do the following:

```
spinnerDialog.bindOnSpinerListener(new OnSpinerItemClick() {
@Override
public void onClick(String item, int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NewActivity.this,PrescriptionActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("doctor",String.valueOf(items.get(position)));            // here
    NewActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```